# How to detect scrollTo plugin is currently scrolls?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

How can i detect [**scrollTo**](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin is currently scrolls moving? like jQuery `:animated` selector.

```
if ( $('.ele').is(':animated') ) {
    $('.ele').animate({'left':'1000px'},5000);
    // .ele will only animate while it is not animating
    // i prevent repeat animation
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
el = $('.ele');

if(!el.hasClass('scrolling')) {
    el.addClass('scrolling');
    $.scrollTo( '#xxx', 1000, {onAfter: function() { el.removeClass('scrolling'); }});
}
```